# Listening to sounds works on the iPhone simulator but not on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, microphone, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to process a blowing sound in my iPhone app. I tried both solutions below. They both work fine in the simulator but not on my device.

- http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/
- https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener

I have seen similar questions around this topic but haven't find an answer yet. Do I need to turn on something in my app or settings?

Answer (score 0):

Diferent sound cards have different 'gains' or amplifications. I had an issue with an app that detected DTMF sounds. It worked perfectly on my pc but not on other machines.

Phones also have noise cancellation systems and that may be causing the issue. Have you tried diferent devices?

Maybe you should create your own app that renders a sound pitch value and see what happens...